# How to join two fixed male pipes

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I'm reassembling the gas line to my hot water heater. I'm at the last joint and I have the problem shown in Fig. 1.

I need to join A to B where A and B are both male and both fixed at the other end. So I'm considering using a coupler C. The problem is, no matter which way I rotate C, it's going to loosen at either A or B while tightening at the other. (And I need C to tighten at both A and B.)

How do I solve this problem and join A to B? Is there maybe a different fitting to use? Am I missing something, either obvious or not-so-obvious?

##### Fig.1. Union of two male, fixed pieces of pipe

[image]

Comment: At the right mix with air, gas can be _explosive_. In Theory pipefitting for gas is straightforward, in practice the risks inherent in an error -- which may not be immediately obvious -- are such that I want it done by someone who is licensed, insured (your own insurance won't cover self-inflicted damage), and has already made their mistakes and had them corrected under expert supervision. There are folks who will disagree; that's fine as long as me and mine are out of the potential blast radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like a [pipe union](https://www.discounthydraulichose.com/product_p/65-union.htm). You might have to check with local codes though because you might need have the union at the appliance with gas lines. I am not 100% sure--a plumber would know.

Answer (score -2):

Put a pipe wrench on the coupling when you are tightening both Male ends of the pipe and bear down on it.  This will ensure the Coupling will not move and loosed from the other connection.  It only needs to get so tight after that you are over working your self.

Comment: Except that both pipes are attached at the _other_ ends from where they need the final fitting. Screwing the coupling on one is easy. Screwing the coupling on the other using your technique will either twist the pipe or cause the other end to unscrew.